# ValueError while importing data from a file using Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I keep getting `ValueError: could not convert string to float:' '.`

The code I used is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
X, Y = np.loadtxt('/Users/sul/Desktop/2,54,51PM.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
    
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.title('Line Graph using NUMPY')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

The file contains two columns and over 1000 rows, like this:

```
1413.541000000  0.001121856
1413.548812500  0.001122533
1413.556625000  0.001121994
1413.564437500  0.001120641
1413.572250000  0.001120932
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Look up how to load txt file lines into a list.

Comment: It seems like the data inside is separated by " " instead of ",". Please change `delimiter=' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it looks that the values are not comma-separated, rather separated by a single space, which causes the error as the values are being interpreted as strings. Change `delimiter = ','` to `delimiter = ' '`, and it should work. See the result below:

[image: Fig]

Comment: white space is the default delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line from your code:

```
X, Y = np.loadtxt('/Users/sul/Desktop/2,54,51PM.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

If your data file looks like the sample you posted, then there is no comma being used as a delimiter.

It seems like it's looking at these two float values separated by a *space* and interpreting that as a String.

You need to match the delimiter.